# About file handling in Javascript on Linux

Tags: javascript, linux, file, firefox, browser-addons

I'm developing an addon for Firefox browser. My addon is intended to work on Linux platform specifically. **How can I handle a file in Javascript on Linux?** I've Googled a lot on this and all I got was file handling in Javascript on Windows using ActiveX objects. Is there any way to do the same on Linux? The type of file I wanted to create and handle is just text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mozilla Development Center has some really great reusable XPCOM components for managing files.  Check out the nsIFile component documentation below:

Reading, writing files:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I//O#Navigating_with_.0ansIFile

General information on nsIFile:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I//O#nsIFile_and_path_strings

In short, when developing a Firefox Add-on, your JavaScript has special permissions when loaded in the XUL markup using a "chrome URL".  This JavaScript can read and write to the filesystem natively, for Windows, Mac, and Linux.  Thus, there is no need to use Flash or any third-party plug-ins.

Comment: meh, that's for extensions, but not for web pages.

Comment: @J-16 SDiZ - Doesn't the OP's question indicate that he's writing a Firefox Extension/Add-on?